# How do I find the Jenkins workspace folders which are gobbling up GBs of my disk space?

Tags: jenkins

Some of my Jenkins' workspace folders are consuming up all my Disk Space.

How can I detect them?

How do I delete them?

Answer (score 0):

**How to Detect**

Command

```
println new ProcessBuilder('sh','-c',' du -ah --max-depth=3 /var/jenkins_home/workspace | sort -k 1 -h -r | head -n 30').redirectErrorStream(true).start().text
```

What does it do?

- Calculates folder wise total disk usage
- Sort the output based on human readable content [ Sorted by Mib/ Gib etc ]

**How to Delete**

```
println new ProcessBuilder('sh','-c',' du -ah --max-depth=7 /var/jenkins_home/workspace | sort -k 1 -h -r | head -n 2| xargs rm -rf ').redirectErrorStream(true).start().text
```